# How can I deserialize JSON containing delimited JSON?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a problem with deserializing a Json-string to an object.

This is a sample json i receive from a webservice:

```
{
    "GetDataResult":
                 "{
                     \"id\":1234,
                     \"cityname\":\"New York\",
                     \"temperature\":300,
                  }"
}
```

And I have a class CityData that looks like this

```
[JsonObject("GetDataResult")]
public class CityData
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cityname")]
    public string CityName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("temperature")]
    public int Temperature { get; set; }
}
```

I try to deserialize the json with a call of the method DeserializeObject

```
var cityData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CityData>(response);
```

but the root element seems to make problems...

Do you guys know how I can fix it, so that I receive a CityData-object with the data filled in?

Comment: What is `response`? The value of the `GetDataResult` property in your JSON is a string, so that's not going to deserialize to the properties the way you expect.

Comment: The web service is spitting up bad JSON.  It's technically legal, but obviously not what you want.  The escaped string quotes in there...it's all bad.

Comment: Chances are he's using WCF's terrible "wrapping" of the JSON, or something like that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The json response contains an object that within itself contains a json string representing the data result.

You need to deserialize twice, once for the response and one more for the data result.

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(responseStr);
var dataResult = (string)response["GetDataResult"];
var cityData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CityData>(dataResult);
```

Comment: You can avoid deserialize twice, if you write custom `JsonConverter` and use `LINQ to JSON`.

Comment: Of course, but then you'd have to write the converter. This will be the simplest fix for this, at least until he'd need a more robust solution.

Comment: Cast to string is throwing an error. I used ToString() instead

Comment: @RomanGudkov, apparently your data is not a string, it's probably an object already. Just cast to a `JObject` or whatever the appropriate type it is. There's no sense in reparsing it if you don't have to.