# deserialize part of json string (array) in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have a json string like this:

```
{  
"Results":[  
  {  
   "attr1": "value1",
   "attr2": "value2",
   "A": "value_a",
   "B": "value_b",
   "C": "value_c", 
   "GuestValues":[  
        {  
            "A": "value_a",
            "B": "value_b",
            "C": "value_c"
        },
        {  
            "A": "value_a",
            "B": "value_b",
            "C": "value_c"
        },
        {  
            "A": "value_a",
            "B": "value_b",
            "C": "value_c"
        }
}
],
"TotalResults":1,
"MilliSeconds":11
}
```

I want to deserialize only the GuestValues array. I created a class like this:

```
public class GuestValue
{
    public string A;
    public string B;
    public string C;
}

public class GuestValueResult
{
    public List<GuestValue> GuestValues { get; set; }
    public in TotalResults { get; set; }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
GuestValueResult guestValues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GuestValueResult>(jsongString);
```

But it doesn't work. I tried a lot, once somehow, it only gives me back the first `"A"`, `"B"`, `"C"` in the jsonString, the one above the `"GuestValues"`, I don't want that group of data. I only want those inside `"GuestValues"`. Please help.

Comment: What exact JSON string do you pass in? It would be easier to write the JSON class for the complete JSON string, I don't think the deserializer is nice enough to check what part of the string it can serialize and give that back to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize partial JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410511/deserialize-partial-json)

Comment: Also see: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.  You're missing a `]` before the ending `}
],
"TotalResults":1,
"MilliSeconds":11
}`.  I assume this is a typo?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use Linq to JSON (part of JSON.NET) to access the relevant node, then deserialize it:

```
var root = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var guestValues = root["Results"][0]["GuestValues"].ToObject<GuestValue[]>();
```

Comment: Actually it should be `ToObject<List<GuestValue>>` shouldn't it?  (As opposed to `GuestValueResult`)

Comment: @BrianRogers, ah, yes, I got them mixed up... thanks

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed the array in the JSON... fixed

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how the code you posted returns any useful value at all given that you have an Results array which is not mapped.

You need to create another class like this

```
 public class ResultsResult
 {
    public GuestValueResult[] Results { get; set; }
 }
```

And then deserialize using the class

```
 ResultsResult guestValues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultsResult>(jsongString);
```

You'll then get what you expect.

Comment: this works, but it makes me having 3 classes which is not so cool. I'll upvote your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I thought that was the direction you wanted to take, given your existing code. Use what's best for your scenario. Thanks!