# Best method to deserialize partial object using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, deserialization

*Disclaimer: There are many topics on this subject, however so far I found only one on the topic of partial deserialisation [thisone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410511/deserialize-partial-json), which already is a couple of years old*

**The question:** What is the easiest way in json.net, yet without much overhead, to deserialize a partial JSON string to object?

Given a JSON object:

```
{
    "message":"Login successful",
    "data":{
        "firstname":"John",
        "lastname":"Doe",
    }
}
```

and an object:

```
public class UserData
{
    [JsonProperty("firstname")]
    public string FirstName;

    [JsonProperty("lastname")]
    public string LastName;
}
```

than, there are many methods you can use. e.g. create another object that holds a variable `UserData data` and deserialize to that object. However, if you want to access FirstName, you'll always have to add the `data` (`data.FirstName`) which is.. not nice.

Another method (as in the post linked above) is to deserialize the object to dynamic/var, get the data part of it, serialize it and feed that string to the

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSONString);
UserData User = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.UserData>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj["data"]));
```

Yes, it works well, but perhaps a bit much overhead?
Another option is to use a custom JsonConverter, but that seems to be allot of code for such a simple thing.

I was hoping to use something like

```
[JsonProperty("data.firstname")]
public string FirstName;
```

or another setting, to let json.net know it should use the path `data` for the deserialisation of the JSON string to `UserData`, but I havent found such a thing in the documentation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This what you're looking for?  [Can I specify a path in an attribute to map a property in my class to a child property in my JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33088462).

Comment: @dbc Thank you, didnt see that method yet; it's most certainly a nice addition to the list. However, this requires a line of code for each item in `data` to properly assign it to the appropriate variable in the object. Meaning that if there are 100 variables in data, you need 100 lines to assign each of them. *Edit:* didn't look far enough down. This actually might be the best way to do it!

Comment: @dbc this works better than I expected (the fancy part that Brian Rogers has in his post). Please mark this question as duplicate, or post the link as answer so I can accept.