# C# Converting mixed JSON into an object

Tags: c#, json

Yo Guys,

I'm currently trying to pass some mixed JSON, and was wondering if it was possible to do anything like the following?

```
struct example_data 
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> information {get; set;}
}

class TestClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test_string = @"{'EventSpecificInformation':
                                   {
                                   'measure':'' 
                                   ,'Long name':'test_name' 
                                   ,'Short name':'test_s_name' 
                                   ,'Description':''
                                   ,'Status':'Real (Imported)'
                                   ,'Viewers':['Everyone']
                                   ,'Modifiers':['Supervisor only']
                                   ,'calculation':''
                                   }
                               }"

        example_data deserialized_entry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<example_data>(test_string)
    }
}
```

As you would expect the above code snippet fails, but I was hoping I could avoid wrapping each JSON entry in a JSON array or having to create a custom JSON reader in C#.

Any advice on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is "mixed" JSON?  It's just JSON.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/8972079/7968203, should do what you want if i understand you correctly

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410511/how-can-i-deserialize-json-containing-delimited-json

Comment: `test_string = test_string.Replace("'", "\"");` Also, you're missing a `;` at the end of `test_string` assignment. You need to replace `'` with `"`, it will then be valid.

Comment: By mixed, I mean a mixture of JSON objects and JSON arrays.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ - The semi-colon is a typo, and this string is read fine, even with single quotes.

Comment: @Andy it's not valid `json`... didn't say it *couldn't be read*.

Comment: @Andy We refer to JSON that contains objects and arrays as simply "JSON".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like what you're looking for is to parse a JSON string into a dynamic object, like so:

```
dynamic myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(@"{'EventSpecificInformation':
                               {
                               'measure':'' 
                               ,'Long name':'test_name' 
                               ,'Short name':'test_s_name' 
                               ,'Description':''
                               ,'Status':'Real (Imported)'
                               ,'Viewers':['Everyone']
                               ,'Modifiers':['Supervisor only']
                               ,'calculation':''
                               }
                           }");

string desc = myObject.EventSpecificInformation.Description;
string longName = myObject.EventSpecificInformation["Long name"];
```

This is likely your best option if you don't have an explicit static model for your JSON input. For properties without a space in their name you can reference them directly using [member access syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#member-access-operator-), for those with a space you can reference them using [indexer access syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#indexer-access).

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, thanks for your suggestion! Sorry, it took me so long to update. Marking your answer as correct!

Answer (score 2):

> As you would expect the above code snippet fails

```
string test_string = @"{'EventSpecificInformation':
                               {
                               'measure':'' 
                               ,'Long name':'test_name' 
                               ,'Short name':'test_s_name' 
                               ,'Description':''
                               ,'Status':'Real (Imported)'
                               ,'Viewers':['Everyone']
                               ,'Modifiers':['Supervisor only']
                               ,'calculation':''
                               }
                           }"
```

In the above you're clearly missing an ending `;` at `test_string` assignment, this wont compile, fix this first (I'm sure it's a type-o). Next, *this isn't valid* `json`, you see all the `'` in that `json`, it should be quotes: `"`. So in short, just replace the bad characters...

```
 string test_string = @"{'EventSpecificInformation':
                               {
                               'measure':'' 
                               ,'Long name':'test_name' 
                               ,'Short name':'test_s_name' 
                               ,'Description':''
                               ,'Status':'Real (Imported)'
                               ,'Viewers':['Everyone']
                               ,'Modifiers':['Supervisor only']
                               ,'calculation':''
                               }
                           }".Replace("'", "\"");
```

*Note* - As far as deserializing your `json`, create a new question with what you've tried (after fixing this), what isn't working and expected output; you've multiple issues, let's address one at a time.

Comment: It parses fine. I was hoping I could take my non-array objects, and have C# just make a size one list with the entry.

Comment: Shouldn't `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{'a':'aa','b':'bb'}")` successfully deserialize ? Correct me i am wrong, but Single Quotes should not be a problem

Comment: @AnuViswan yes, it will deserialize `'`, the problem is it's not valid `json`, it fails all RFC's... If trying to deserialize into a type, it will fail.

Comment: @Andy to make the size one list, you need to use a Custom JsonConverter which does the same. Please check my answer.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ How about deserializing to `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>`, with help of a JsonConverter which Converts Single objects to Array ? Could you pls check my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can push the results to `Dictionary`

```
string test_string = @"{'EventSpecificInformation':
                        {
                        'measure':'' 
                        ,'Long name':'test_name' 
                        ,'Short name':'test_s_name' 
                        ,'Description':''
                        ,'Status':'Real (Imported)'
                        ,'Viewers':['Everyone']
                        ,'Modifiers':['Supervisor only']
                        ,'calculation':''
                        }
                    }".Replace("'", "\""); 

var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>>(test_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you do not want to use a static model,the problem with the code is that it doesn't match signature of your Json. The Json comprises of a `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,List<string>>`. However, there is another concern.

Some of the values in inner `Dictionary` is not `List<string>`. Instead, they are strings. For example,

```
'Short name':'test_s_name'
```

For this purpose you need to use a a Custom `JsonConverter` which if the values is not a array, converts the single string value to list. For example, consider the following Custom `JsonConverter`.

```
class SingleOrArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
{
return (objectType == typeof(List<T>));
}

public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
{
return token.ToObject<List<T>>();
}
return new List<T> { token.ToObject<T>() };
}

public override bool CanWrite
{
get { return false; }
}

public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
throw new NotImplementedException();
}
}
```

Now, you could deserialize your Json as

```
string test_string = @"{'EventSpecificInformation':
                                   {
                                   'measure':'' 
                                   ,'Long name':'test_name' 
                                   ,'Short name':'test_s_name' 
                                   ,'Description':''
                                   ,'Status':'Real (Imported)'
                                   ,'Viewers':['Everyone']
                                   ,'Modifiers':['Supervisor only']
                                   ,'calculation':''
                                   }
                               }";

var deserialized_entry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string, List<string>>>>(test_string,new SingleOrArrayConverter<string>());
```

**Output**

[image]